# UILabel - set custom fonts

Tags: ios, uilabel

I want to add GillSans-Bold font to a UILabel.
I have set it in the xib file , and I'm also setting it up in my class as follows :

```
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Bold" size:18]];
```

But , it doesn't seem to work for me.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: This is helpful: http://iosfonts.com - shows what iOS version has which stock fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this to be working I had to add this font in my project directory , and added this font in the Info.Plist file

Answer (score 12):

iPhone 4.3 doesn't have Gill Sans, but iPad has it since 3.2.1.

See this [list comparing fonts for iPad 4.3 and iPhone 4.3](http://www.whatsyourdigitaliq.com/fonts-available-in-various-versions-of-ios/). To be sure, this is how you get the list of fonts available on your device:

```
for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
    for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", fontName);
    }
}
```

If it says

```
GillSans
GillSans-Bold
GillSans-BoldItalic
GillSans-Italic
```

then `[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Bold" size:18]` should return a valid font.

Answer (score 2):

Does the font GillSans-Bold exist? Check if `[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Bold" size:18]` returns an `UIFont`, not `null`.

Comment: I tried this, and it's returning 'null' . The only font available in **Gill Sans** family is _GillSans_. Thanks. But is there any way I can  render the UILabel text in GillSans-Bold font ?

Answer (score 1):

Swift

```
let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 16)
    label.text = "Your text here"
```

P.S. Before that you must:

1. Add custom font in project

[image]

2. Add font names in Info.plist file

[image]

3. Add font files in Copy Bundle Resources

[image]

After that you can also use this fonts in storyboards

[image]