# Swift 4 set custom font programmatically

Tags: swift

How to set Custom font to UILabel or Any Other UIView programmatically (if it is possible)
i know how to do it in storyboard but not programmatically
thank you

this what i did
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UILabel - set custom fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151262/uilabel-set-custom-fonts)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Fonts Bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46604829/custom-fonts-bug)

Comment: Please see "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)", and "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)".

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can try

```
lbl.font = UIFont(name:"FontAwesome",size:15)
```

the name should be the font name as it is when you install it . not as the file name in your case was **Noto Kufi Arabic** instead of  **NotoKufiArabicRegular**

> click the font and open it with Font Book , then install it after that specify exactly the name shown in the parameter in the line above

Comment: you have to make sure you add the font to plist , and target memberShip is checked and copied for the font

Comment: yes all done , target membership and i declare it on info.plist, but not working yet

Comment: click the font and open it with **Font Book** , then install it after that specify exactly the name shown in the parameter in the line above

Comment: that  was helpful tha name was Noto Kufi Arabic

Comment: If you need to see the available font styles for your font check this: UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: "FontName")

Comment: 1. **Font.otf** select the file. 2. On the right panel (detailed information) find the checkbox for **Target Membership** and make sure it is selected!

Answer (score 20):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIFont {

    public enum OpenSansType: String {
        case extraboldItalic = "-ExtraboldItalic"
        case semiboldItalic = "-SemiboldItalic"
        case semibold = "-Semibold"
        case regular = ""
        case lightItalic = "Light-Italic"
        case light = "-Light"
        case italic = "-Italic"
        case extraBold = "-Extrabold"
        case boldItalic = "-BoldItalic"
        case bold = "-Bold"
    }

    static func OpenSans(_ type: OpenSansType = .regular, size: CGFloat = UIFont.systemFontSize) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: "OpenSans\(type.rawValue)", size: size)!
    }

    var isBold: Bool {
        return fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitBold)
    }

    var isItalic: Bool {
        return fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitItalic)
    }

}
```

Use:

```
self.numberLabel.font = UIFont.OpenSans(.bold, size: 20)
```

Comment: this is not exactly the problem here. you just encapsulated inside an extension. the problem here is how to configure and setup the fonts inside the project.

Answer (score 8):

If the previous answer doesn't help, you didn't configure all links correctly at xCode for sure!

1. Add this by drag and drop to your files on the left side of the project.
2. Add your CUSTOM fonts to the info.plist file.
3. Make sure that you've linked all custom fonts you need: "Build Phases" -> "Copy Bundle Resources" -> "+" add your font.

More information you can get here:
[Medium.com](https://medium.com/@AttiaMo/custom-fonts-in-ios-apps-global-settings-and-localizations-e6193918e35c)

Comment: 3rd step helped for me

Comment: 3rd step helped for me

Comment: This was helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine for Me **swift 5**

```
extension UIFont {
  public enum fontType: String {
    case regular = ""
    case kFontBlackItalic = "Montserrat-BlackItalic"
    case kFontExtraBoldItalic = "Montserrat-ExtraBoldItalic"
    case kFontBoldItalic = "Montserrat-BoldItalic"
    case kFontSemiBoldItalic = "Montserrat-SemiBoldItalic"
    case kFontMediumItalic = "Montserrat-MediumItalic"
    case kFontItalic = "Montserrat-Italic"
    case kFontLightItalic = "Montserrat-LightItalic"
    case kFontBlack = "Montserrat-Black"
    case kFontExtraLightItalic = "Montserrat-ExtraLightItalic"
    case kFontThinItalic = "Montserrat-ThinItalic"
    case kFontExtraBold = "Montserrat-ExtraBold"
    case kFontBold = "Montserrat-Bold"
    case kFontSemiBold = "Montserrat-SemiBold"
    case kFontMedium = "Montserrat-Medium"
    case kFontRegular = "Montserrat-Regular"
    case kFontLight = "Montserrat-Light"
    case kFontExtraLight = "Montserrat-ExtraLight"
    case kFontThin = "Montserrat-Thin"
}
    
static func setFont(_ type: fontType = .regular, size: CGFloat = UIFont.systemFontSize) -> UIFont {
    return UIFont(name: type.rawValue, size: size)!
    }
 }
```

Comment: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value . Getting this crash